# Convert Single Object into Multiple Object c#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a list as below

[image]

I want to convert this into a list which looks like this

[image]

Can anybody suggest some sample code?

I have tried the bellow code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mockForDataColection = Mock.MockForDataColection();
        Factory f = new Factory();
        List<ResultSet> rl = new List<ResultSet>();
        var groups = mockForDataColection.GroupBy(x => new { group1 = x.GroupIdOne, group2 = x.GroupIdTwo, group3 = x.GroupIdThree }).ToList();

        f.Name = mockForDataColection.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Key == "Chamber").Value;
        f.RunNumber = mockForDataColection.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Key == "RunNumber").Value;
        var groupBy = mockForDataColection.GroupBy(c => c.GroupIdThree).Skip(1);
        foreach (var dataCollection in groupBy)
        {
            ResultSet r = new ResultSet();
            r.BarCode = dataCollection.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key == "BarCode").Value;
            r.IsPassed = dataCollection.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key == "IsPassed").Value;
            rl.Add(r);

        }
        f.ResultSet = rl;
    }


}

public class DataCollection
{
    public int GroupIdOne { get; set; }
    public int GroupIdTwo { get; set; }
    public int GroupIdThree { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

}

public class Factory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RunNumber { get; set; }
    public List<ResultSet> ResultSet { get; set; }


}

public class ResultSet
{
    public string BarCode { get; set; }
    public string IsPassed { get; set; }
    public int FailiureCode { get; set; }
}

public static class Mock
{
    public static List<DataCollection> MockForDataColection()
    {
        List<DataCollection> dataCollectionList = new List<DataCollection>();
        DataCollection dataCollection = new DataCollection
        {
            GroupIdOne = 1,
            GroupIdTwo = 1,
            GroupIdThree = 0,
            Key = "Chamber",
            Value = "Test Chamber"
        };
        DataCollection dataCollection1 = new DataCollection
        {
            GroupIdOne = 1,
            GroupIdTwo = 1,
            GroupIdThree = 0,
            Key = "RunNumber",
            Value = "2"
        };

        DataCollection dataCollection2 = new DataCollection
        {
            GroupIdOne = 1,
            GroupIdTwo = 2,
            GroupIdThree = 3,
            Key = "IsPassed",
            Value = "P"
        };

        DataCollection dataCollection3 = new DataCollection
        {
            GroupIdOne = 1,
            GroupIdTwo = 2,
            GroupIdThree = 3,
            Key = "BarCode",
            Value = "PQWERT"
        };


        DataCollection dataCollection4 = new DataCollection
        {
            GroupIdOne = 1,
            GroupIdTwo = 2,
            GroupIdThree = 4,
            Key = "IsPassed",
            Value = "F"
        };

        DataCollection dataCollection5 = new DataCollection
        {
            GroupIdOne = 1,
            GroupIdTwo = 2,
            GroupIdThree = 4,
            Key = "BarCode",
            Value = "IUTYY"
        };

        dataCollectionList.Add(dataCollection);
        dataCollectionList.Add(dataCollection1);
        dataCollectionList.Add(dataCollection2);
        dataCollectionList.Add(dataCollection3);
        dataCollectionList.Add(dataCollection4);
        dataCollectionList.Add(dataCollection5);

        return dataCollectionList;
    }
}
```

I think it's not a good code. Please suggest some other easy way to achieve this one.

Need to convert the data collection class into Factory class. In data, collection class has Key and Value Properties. Key is act as a property in Factory class Value is Value. Based on the GroupId Only we will decide it will go to Parent class (Factory) or child class (ResultSet).

GroupId One value is same means it all under a single entity. GroupId Two value differs means it is a related entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have completely edited the answer, changed everything so that it is right and according to what was asked.

**listA, your data to be grouped**

```
var listA = new List<DataCollection>
{
    new DataCollection { GroupIdOne = 1, GroupIdTwo = 1, GroupIdThree = 0, Key = "Chamber", Value = "Test Chamber" },
    new DataCollection { GroupIdOne = 1, GroupIdTwo = 1, GroupIdThree = 0, Key = "RunNumber", Value = "2"   },
    new DataCollection { GroupIdOne = 1, GroupIdTwo = 2, GroupIdThree = 3, Key = "IsPassed", Value = "P"  },
    new DataCollection { GroupIdOne = 1, GroupIdTwo = 2, GroupIdThree = 3, Key = "BarCode", Value = "PQWERT" },
    new DataCollection { GroupIdOne = 1, GroupIdTwo = 2, GroupIdThree = 4, Key = "IsPassed", Value = "F"},
    new DataCollection { GroupIdOne = 1, GroupIdTwo = 2, GroupIdThree = 4, Key = "BarCode", Value = "IUTYY"}
};
```

**listB**

```
var listB = listA
    .Where(x => x.Key.Contains("BarCode"))
    .GroupBy(g => new {g.GroupIdOne, g.GroupIdTwo, g.GroupIdThree, g.Key, g.Value})
    .Select(s =>
        new ResultSet
        {
            BarCode = s.Key.Value,
            IsPassed = listA.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Key.Equals("IsPassed")
                                                 && a.GroupIdOne == s.Key.GroupIdOne
                                                 && a.GroupIdTwo == s.Key.GroupIdTwo
                                                 && a.GroupIdThree == s.Key.GroupIdThree

                       )?.Value ?? ""
        })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: In Class A BarCode and Status both are keys It may be differ

Comment: Please Check with my DataCollection Class

Comment: @Niventh see my answer now, I've rewritten it